# ReactJS + Auth0 Sample app using the original logged in email. How to clear?

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I am following the tutorial here:
https://github.com/auth0-blog/auth0-react-sample

I have most of the authentication working but get the following issue:

The first time I log in (after a cache clear) it asks me for gmail username. If I select the appropriate one, it logs me in. If I logout, and click login it never asks me again, it just uses the original one I entered.

If I enter an invalid gmail, it doesn't login but never asks again.

Either way, I suspect it's using the original response that it gets back (either authenticated or not).

Is there a way I can change it so that if I click the logout button (or it fails to login) it deletes the response.

I believe this post from 2018 is similar but I'm not sure how to modify it to today:
https://community.auth0.com/t/does-not-show-user-login-prompt-anymore-after-the-first-logging-in/16504

I'm new to react/auth0 but here are what I think to be the relevant files:

**auth0-provider-with-history.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const Auth0ProviderWithHistory = ({ children }) => {
  
  const history = useHistory();
  const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
  const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
  const audience = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_AUDIENCE;

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
    history.push(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
      audience={audience}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};

export default Auth0ProviderWithHistory;
```

**protected-route.js**

```
// src/auth/protected-route.js

import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { withAuthenticationRequired } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import { Loading } from "../components/index";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component, ...args }) => (
  <Route
    component={withAuthenticationRequired(component, {
      onRedirecting: () => <Loading />,
    })}
    {...args}
  />
);

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**login-button.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const LoginButton = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
  return (
    <button
      className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
      onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}
    >
      Log In
    </button>
  );
};

export default LoginButton;
```

**logout-button.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const LogoutButton = () => {
  const { logout } = useAuth0();
  return (
    <button
      className="btn btn-danger btn-block"
      onClick={() =>
        logout({
          returnTo: window.location.origin,
        })
      }
    >
      Log Out
    </button>
  );
};

export default LogoutButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I was able to get this working by adding `localStorage.clear();` in appropriate locations to delete anything that was stored.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Specifically:

**logout-button.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const LogoutButton = () => {
  const { logout } = useAuth0();
  localStorage.clear(); // this clears the old email address
  return (
    <button
      className="btn btn-danger btn-block"
      onClick={() =>{
        logout({
          returnTo: window.location.origin,
        })
      }
      }
    >
      Log Out
    </button>
  );
};

export default LogoutButton;
```

**app.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

import { NavBar, Footer, Loading } from "./components";
import { Home, Profile, ExternalApi } from "./views";
import ProtectedRoute from "./auth/protected-route";

import "./app.css";

const App = () => {
  const { isLoading, logout,  error} = useAuth0();
  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }

  if (typeof error !== 'undefined' && error.error === "unauthorized") { // The user does not exist. Completely log them out.
    
    localStorage.clear(); 
    logout({
      returnTo: window.location.origin,
    });
    
  }

  return (
    <div id="app" className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
      <NavBar />
      <div className="container flex-grow-1">
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/external-api" component={ExternalApi} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```